# Face reflects light differently to others

Tags: modeling

I'm currently working on a Stryker, i'v came across a problem which make it so one of the faces reflects light differently than all of the others.

Thanks to anyone who helps/attempt's to help :D
Here is a picture of it
[image]

Comment: In case of question about unexpected results of reflection it would be good to include screenshot with that reflection. And if possible a file.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem related to the normals.  To correct it, go into edit mode and select everything. (This can be done by pressing *A* once or twice.)  Then, click *Shading/UVs* > *Normals* > *Recalculate*.  If this does not work, select the single face and click *Shading/UVs* > *Normals* > *Flip Direction*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but didn't work :/

Comment: Strange . . .  Could you upload your .blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?

Answer (score 0):

If you open up your preference and look under the System Tab you will see *Solid OpenGL lights*. They are the defaults to help you see 3D surfaces that face different directions - it is just an aid and does not affect the render. If a face goes severely dark then the chances are the Normal's are flipped. In your case nothing to worry about...

[image]

If you want to check your Normals though, there is always the button under *Mesh Display*.

[image]